# Ferramentas e testes para melhorar segurança de um sistema?

Tags: php, segurança

Olá, pesquisando um pouco sobre o assunto de segurança, fiquei na dúvida se existe alguma ferramenta que testa a segurança um sistema PHP, tentando aplicar diversas formas de invasão no sistema. Pois queria saber se meus sistemas são seguros, uso as melhores práticas em questões de segurança, mas nunca vi em funcionamento.

Há alguma ferramenta que faça testes de invasão automaticamente? Como ataques de injeção SQL e XSS. Se sim, como usa-la? (breve explicação)

Comment: Utilizo o **[Acunetix](https://www.acunetix.com/)** para testes rápidos em meus websites, ele possui inúmeras ferramentas inclusas, caso deseja saber mais sobre ele, entre no site e solicite uma versão de teste. Desculpe não poder dar mais detalhes.

Comment: O Acunetix pode ser caro para muitas pessoas, embora eles ofereçam um modo online que é bem mais barato. Mas, o que é mais intrigante é que a versão de teste possui uma restrição e apenas pode ser usado cinco endereços pre-definidos e que são do próprio Acunetix, mas existe um "bug" que permite usar qualquer um. É estranho um software para buscar vulnerabilidade ser tão vulnerável assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há várias ferramentas. Elas testam a aplicação e o servidor WEB, independente da linguagem em que foi desenvolvida.

Para testar, basta informar a URL e o tipo de testes.

OBS: As versões gratuitas possuem limitações, mas já ajudam muito a identificar falhas de segurança na aplicação e no servidor.

Seguem algumas delas:

- [N-Stalker Free](https://www.nstalker.com/products/editions/free/download/)
- [Netsparker Community Edition](https://www.netsparker.com/)
- [OWASP WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WebScarab_Getting_Started)
- [Hp - Scrawlr](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Protect-Your-Assets/Finding-SQL-Injection-with-Scrawlr/ba-p/2408262)